# Is there a way to concat a list of DataFrames using regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, spyder

I have multiple DataFrames that I wish to append. I get my desired output with:

```
bigdf = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6])
```

These DataFrames are stored in my variable explorer using the Spyder IDE.

This process works fine, but can get a bit tedious when typing them all out.

But let's say the DataFrames I wish to append all have very similar names, only separated by a numbered suffix.
Eg; outcome1, outcome2, outcome3, etc...

I am wondering, **is there is a way to append all my desired DataFrames using a single regular expression pattern to find the names of the DataFrames?**

The regex pattern would be: `'^outcome'` to gather a list of all DataFrames found in my variable explorer that commonly have the 'outcome' prefix.

Please forgive and correct me if I miss anything, as this is my first question.

Comment: can you provide a bit more in terms of input data, as well as expected output

Comment: I don't use Spyder IDE...  however I would expect a list comprehension of DFs from available variable would work well

Comment: My input would be something like `bigdf = pd.concat(list('^outcome'))` even though that obviously doesn't work, but it should (hopefully) show the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

outcome1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1], 'b':[3]})
outcome2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3], 'b':[4]})

bigdf = eval("pd.concat([" + ", ".join(list(filter(lambda x: re.match('^outcome', x) ,dir()))) + "])")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pandas.

But I make an assumption that you're able to make pandas dataframes as iterator or iterable,

then you can do prefix search with **re** package.

```
import re

for dFrame in dataframes:
  if re.search( r'^outcome', dFrame.name): # return None if nothing found
    bigdf += pd.concat([dFrame])
    # I'm not sure the pandas syntax, just append the found dataframe
```

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding anything.
Thx.